# How to authenticate and authorize the token from Angular 2 web app using Azure ad b2c at ASP.net Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular2-services, azure-ad-b2c

I am using angular 2 at client side and I want to allow the consumers to login using the social accounts like Google, Facebook etc.

For that I am using the Azure ad b2c.

I want to secure the Web API with a token from the angular 2 web app.

How can I achieve that?

I have tried `msal` library (preview) in Angular 2 for authenticating the user using Azure ad b2c. But I am not able to authorize the token at Web API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [Angular 4 example w/ MSAL.js](https://github.com/Gimly/NetCoreAngularAzureB2CMsal).

Also, [this blog post](https://saraford.net/2017/11/29/securing-an-asp-net-core-web-api-2-using-azure-ad-b2c/) is a good guide for securing Web API.  There's also a good sample project on GitHub: [An ASP.NET Core 2.0 web API with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi).

Comment: I have used msal on angular side and all login is handled at angular end. What I wanted to do was handle the azure b2c login from server side(.net web api), for e.g like using login controller for handling the login process. What I wanted to do was to handle the token generation process at web api side.

Comment: [You could **ROPC** for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc).  I would read up on this flow **before** using it though.  You would be taking on **more responsibility** for security if you did this. @Narendra